# Twilio Programmable Chat - Push notifications not arriving

Tags: ios, push-notification, twilio

I'm working on an app that uses the Twilio Programmable Chat API. I've created an APNS development cert for the app and verified that notifications are landing using Pusher. I've created a new push credential in the Programmable Chat console using this cert and checked the "use this credential for sending to a sandbox APN" checkbox. I've updated our `IpMessagingGrant` call to use this credential's Sid. Lastly, I'm registering our device token successfully with the `TwilioChatClient`.

I'm not receiving push notifications for received messages, etc. and not sure what other levers I have at my disposal. If anyone on the team sees this message I'd love to know how I can try to debug this.

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio. Sounds like you've done everything right, so we'd need to look a bit deeper, can you email your Account SID, the chat instance SID and channel SID for the channel you've been testing with to philnash@twilio.com and we'll take a look in the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your credentials are in good shape but notifications are not yet enabled for your chat instance.  This step only needs to be done once per chat instance per notification type:

```
curl -X POST https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/{service sid} \ 
-d 'Notifications.NewMessage.Enabled=true' \
-d 'Notifications.NewMessage.Template=A New message in ${CHANNEL} from ${USER}: ${MESSAGE}' \
-d 'Notifications.NewMessage.Sound=default' \
-u '{twilio account sid}:{twilio auth token}'
```

This should solve the issue you're seeing.  Docs for this can be found here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/push-notification-configuration#push-configuring

Please let us know if you have any questions or this does not get pushes flowing for you.